# Draw arrows over points

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I draw quivers in a matplotlib figure so that they are drawn over the original points.

```
soa = np.array([vec1,vec2])
X,Y,U,V = zip(*soa)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.plot(ax, rotdata[:,0], rotdata[:,1], 'o', c='b')
ax.quiver(X,Y,U,V, angles='xy', scale_units='xy',scale=1,
          width=.02, color='r')
```

I get this with the code above.

[image: result]

This is the result I would like to have

[image: desired result]

Comment: Just so I'm clear on what your question is, you want the scatter points to physically overlay the quiver arrows, instead of the arrows over the points, correct?

Comment: If the answer to the above question is yes, please see the documentation for [zorder](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html)

Comment: I wanted it the other way around but zorder solves this for me, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify an order for both the data points and the arrows by using the zorder kwarg as follows:

```
soa = np.array([vec1,vec2])
X,Y,U,V = zip(*soa)
ax = plt.gca()

ax.plot(ax, rotdata[:,0], rotdata[:,1], 'o', c='b', zorder=1)
ax.quiver(X,Y,U,V, angles='xy', scale_units='xy',scale=1,
      width=.02, color='r',zorder=2)
```